# React - toggle only one button, not all

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, onclick, toggle

I have the app which renders cities from the API and below every city there should be a button to show this city's description. Now, when I click on one button, all buttons change text and show description component.

I saw several similar questions and I know, I should probably use indexes to tell which button should work on click, however I have a problem with aplying it to my code.

```
class CitiesList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            opened: false,
        }
        this.toggleButton = this.toggleButton.bind(this);
    };

    toggleButton() {
        const {opened} = this.state;
        this.setState({
            opened: !opened,
        })
    }


    render() {

        const items = this.props.cities.map((data, index) => (
            <div key={index}>
                <h2>{data.city}</h2>
                <p>PM 2.5 value: {data.value} {data.unit}</p>
                {this.state.opened ? <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" size="small" onClick={this.toggleButton}>Hide city description</Button> : <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" size="small" onClick={this.toggleButton}>Show city description</Button>}
                {this.state.opened && <CityDescription/>}

            </div>
        ));
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    {items}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

In CityDescription component now I have only:

```
class CityDescription extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                description
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: you are setting a true/false flag to show/hide description, so, your state doesn't know which description to show. What you can do is, set the index of the mapped city in the state. For example, if description of city no. 2 is to be shown, set showIndex to 2 in the state, then you can render the description conditionally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by @Muhammad, you can make this work by doing only few changes.

Below code should work:

```
class CitiesList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            opened: false,
        }
    };

    toggleButton = (index) => {
        const {opened} = this.state;
        this.setState({
            opened: {
              ...opened,
              [index]: !opened[index]
            }
        })
    }


    render() {
        const { opened } = this.state;
        const items = this.props.cities.map((data, index) => (
            <div key={index}>
                <h2>{data.city}</h2>
                <p>PM 2.5 value: {data.value} {data.unit}</p>
                {opened[index] ? <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" size="small" onClick={() => this.toggleButton(index)}>Hide city description</Button> : <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" size="small" onClick={() => this.toggleButton(index)}>Show city description</Button>}
                {opened[index] && <CityDescription/>}

            </div>
        ));
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    {items}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need `opened` state for each city. You can do that by keeping array of objects and each object will be containing like this `{id: <it can be index>, opened: <true/false>}`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of Rabi jha works but just few minutes ago I did it different way.

In `CitiesList` I left only

```
const items = this.props.cities.map((data, index) => (
            <div key={index}>
                <h2>{data.city}</h2>
                <p>PM 2.5 value: {data.value} {data.unit}</p>
                <CityDescription/>
            </div>
        ));
```

and the rest I moved to `CityDescription` component and it also works.